# do system level command to unzip a '*.tgz' file

Tags: matlab

I have some zip files that matlab:unzip can't extract.  So I need to use matlab control over the DOS prompt and extract it using another program "7-zip".  How would I do this in Matlab script?  Is there a system level script to allow dos commands?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SYSTEM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function:

```
system('7z e file.tgz')
```

or use `!` (exclamation point) [character](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html):

```
!7z e file.tgz
```

Here is the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/creating-opening-changing-and-deleting-files-and-folders.html#f0-38522) with more details and examples.